# Share local network Docker

Tags: windows, networking, docker

I have installed Docker 1.12.0-rc4 on my Win10 machine using Hyper-V.
I have two containers running a tomcat application and a Metasploit instance both started with the --net="host" option.

From the Metasploit container, I can successfully see the tomcat application running on port :8080

This command downloads the initial page of Tomcat

```
wget 127.0.0.1:8080
```

However when I try to browse 127.0.0.1:8080 from my PC Chrome shows that `127.0.0.1 refused to connect`.

How can I actually let container see each other using (--net=host) and browse them through the network?

PS: I've already changed my docker daemon in order to start with the flag --ip=127.0.0.1 as discussed [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13914#issuecomment-133110028), nothing changed

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why force host networking rather than the default bridge network?

Comment: Because I need to upload a shell on tomcat that will talk with my Metasploit on :4444 but if I set -p 4444:4444 Metasploit tells me the port is already in use (by docker-proxy i think)

Comment: @R0MANARMY is this good?

Comment: Could you map it to some other port, like 10123? The containers should see each other fine, even if they are on a bridge network. That's mostly unrelated to how you access them from the host (on windows).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint, but @Bui answer was right, I've connected to my tomcat instance and with ifconfig i got the eth0 address, so if I use that IP i can see tomcat homepage from my workstation

Comment: Docker on Windows creates a VM and attaches that VM to the virtual switch it creates. Is the IP you're connecting to the same as the IP of that VM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127381/discussion-between-naramsim-and-r0manarmy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you must call from Metasploit container to HOST.
Then, exec into your container and check your HOST_IP (default is 172.0.0.1)
After that, try

```
wget ${Your_host_ip}:8080
```